# Autocomplete functionality lag

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I have a data source of more than 20k values. So when I use ant design autocomplete its taking ages to load the data .. How can I reduce the autocomplete loading speed and reduce the lag.

I have the autocomplete component working fine but needs to reduce the loading speed.

```
<AutoComplete
     ref={this.inputElement}
     value={this.state.currentItem.text}
     dataSource={this.state.keySource}
     style={{ width: 200 }}
     onSelect={onKeywordSelect}
     onSearch={this.handleKeySearch}
     className="text-input form-control" 
     placeholder="Type any gene name, drug name.."
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data source file is too large, you should do that on server side. You should have UI call api with query string, and have server find the matched data and return it.

You may also sort the 20k data in certain way like a tree so the query could be faster or use database.